# Undertow : use Hystrix Observable in Http handler

Tags: asynchronous, rx-java, hystrix, undertow

I managed to setup an Hystrix Command to be called from an Undertow HTTP Handler:

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
    if (exchange.isInIoThread()) {
        exchange.dispatch(this);
        return;
    }
    RpcClient rpcClient = new RpcClient(/* ... */);
    try {
        byte[] response = new RpcCommand(rpcClient).execute();
        // send the response
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // send an error
    }
}
```

This works nice. But now, I would like to use the observable feature of Hystrix, calling `observe` instead of `execute`, making the code non-blocking.

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
    RpcClient rpcClient = new RpcClient(/* ... */);
    new RpcCommand(rpcClient).observe().subscribe(new Observer<byte[]>(){
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
            exchange.setStatusCode(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            exchange.endExchange();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNext(byte[] body) {
            exchange.getResponseHeaders().add(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
            exchange.getResponseSender().send(ByteBuffer.wrap(body));

        }
    });
}
```

As expected (reading the doc), the handler returns immediately and as a consequence, the exchange is ended; when the `onNext` callback is executed, it fails with an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000127: Response has already been sent
at io.undertow.io.AsyncSenderImpl.send(AsyncSenderImpl.java:122)
at io.undertow.io.AsyncSenderImpl.send(AsyncSenderImpl.java:272)
at com.xxx.poc.undertow.DiyServerBootstrap$1$1.onNext(DiyServerBootstrap.java:141)
at com.xxx.poc.undertow.DiyServerBootstrap$1$1.onNext(DiyServerBootstrap.java:115)
at rx.internal.util.ObserverSubscriber.onNext(ObserverSubscriber.java:34)
```

Is there a way to tell Undertow that the handler is doing IO asynchronously? I expect to use a lot of non-blocking code to access database and other services.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should `dispatch()` a Runnable to have the exchange not end when the `handleRequest` method returns. Since the creation of the client and subscription are pretty simple tasks, you can do it on the same thread with `SameThreadExecutor.INSTANCE` like this:

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
    exchange.dispatch(SameThreadExecutor.INSTANCE, () -> {
        RpcClient rpcClient = new RpcClient(/* ... */);
        new RpcCommand(rpcClient).observe().subscribe(new Observer<byte[]>(){
            //...
        });
    });
}
```

(If you do not pass an executor to `dispatch()`, it will dispatch it to the XNIO worker thread pool. If you wish to do the client creation and subscription on your own executor, then you should pass that instead.)